# Transition duration in grid display with grid-template-areas : how to make it work?

Tags: css, css-grid

when I click on button I changed the grid template of my layout from

```
#chatContainer {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header"
        "chat chat chat users"
        "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 350px;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 80px;
}
```

to

```
#chatContainer.resized {
    grid-template-areas:
            "header header header header"
            "chat chat chat chat"
            "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 350px;
    transition-duration: 2s;
```

}

(I make the users part disappear)

But The transition duration has no effect at all.

Is it possible to add some animation/transition effect when changing the grid-template-areas ?

Comment: add your html also

Comment: no, not possible. Consider a different idea like changing width, margin, etc

Answer (score 0):

As you need values the transition-event can change to make the crossover smooth that is not possible by your choosed way to setup the grid.

But it **is possible** if you **just change your setup of the grid**. You only need to use `percentage values` instead of setting your grid up with `grid-template-areas`.

**NOTE:**

1. Example is simplified just to explain/demonstrate technique.
2. Transition added to hover event instead of 'button technique (= adding a class)'. But adding a class as you do in your project should work as well.
3. Using `fr` instead of `%` for your values works as well.
4. In example the borders prevent the grid areas from disappearing completely. If that is an issue to you use grid container for the what they are only (= grid-elements) and add styling to inner content-div-container (=add needed borders there).

See example:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 75% 25%;
    transition: all 2s;         
}

.grid-wrapper > div {
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.chat {
    background: yellow;
}
.user {
    background: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-wrapper:hover {
    grid-template-columns: 100% 0%;
    transition: all 2s;         
}
```

```html
   <h2>Hover it to see how technique works:</h2>

<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="chat">Chat</div>
    <div class="user">User</div>
</div>
```

---

*Update: added two explanations*