# Add css transition while filtering

Tags: jquery, css

I have created the above filtering where the user clicks on the buttons and the items are filtered. I am trying to add also a smooth transition, by my example don't want to cooopeate :)

I added `transition: all 10.3s ease;` on my class but it didn't worked.

What I am missing here ?
Thanks !

```js
$("#filter button").each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {

    var tags = [];
    var filtertag = $(this).attr('data-type');
    tags.push(filtertag);
    console.log("filtertag = " + filtertag);
    if (filtertag === 'all') {
      tags = [];
      $('.record').removeClass('d-none');
    } else {
      $('.record').addClass('d-none');

      for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
        $('.record.' + tags[i]).removeClass('d-none');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.d-inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

#filter {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.list_right {
  color: white;
}

.record {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 10.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="filter" class="d-inline">
  <button type="button" data-type="all" class="">ALL</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="proceeding" class="btn-active">Proceeding</button>
  <button type="button" data-type="journal" class="">Journal Article</button>
</div>

<div class="wrap mcb-wrap mcb-wrap-hwqel1sdl one myfilter valign-top clearfix" style="">
  <div class="mcb-wrap-inner">

    <div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-ko9c4lj4p one column_list record proceeding">
      <div class="list_item lists_2 clearfix">
        <div class="animate fadeIn" data-anim-type="fadeIn">
          <div class="list_right">My text 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-03xff3oxj one column_list record proceeding">
      <div class="list_item lists_2 clearfix">
        <div class="animate fadeIn" data-anim-type="fadeIn">
          <div class="list_right">My text 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-kdy28db1t one column_list record journal">
      <div class="list_item lists_2 clearfix">
        <div class="animate" data-anim-type="fadeIn">
          <div class="list_right">My text 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed:
**Property `display: none` CAN NOT be animated and not used with css transition smoothly**

**Explanation:**

That is because a transition needs to have values is can change 'step by step' spread all over the transition-time.

**Possible standard approach: reducing to zero height instead of `display: none`:**

On approach is to fade out and 'remove' an element by reducing it to zero height. Demonstration see example below this posting. *BUT HEAD UP:* as you see in the example that needs a fix `height` set to the element which will be reduced. It does NOT work with `auto` or `min-height` for property `height`.

**Maybe better approach to your project: change html structure to `grid`:**

To smooth remove / reduce an auto-sized-height element (I assume that is what are you looking for) you can use another html structure. If you can work with `grid` in this case you can easily smoothly reduce an auto-height-row by using transitions.

Yesterday we had a demo on this working horizontal. But same mechanic works on vertical structure as well. If you like you may have a look to that different horizontal example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66742338/9268485
(Note: transitions in that example works on hover!)

---

**Explaining example to approach 1:**

```js
        $("#filter button").each(function () {
            $(this).on("click", function () {

                var tags = [];
                var filtertag = $(this).attr('data-type');
                tags.push(filtertag);
                console.log("filtertag = " + filtertag);
                if (filtertag === 'all') {
                    tags = [];
                    $('.record').removeClass('d-none');
                } else {
                    $('.record').addClass('d-none');

                    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
                        $('.record.' + tags[i]).removeClass('d-none');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
        .d-inline {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #filter {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .list_right {
            color: white;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .record {
            height: 38px;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: blue;
            transition: all 5s ease;
        }
        .d-none {
            height: 0;
            padding: 0 10px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            opacity: 0;

            transition: all 5s ease;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="filter" class="d-inline">
        <button type="button" data-type="all" class="">ALL</button>
        <button type="button" data-type="proceeding" class="btn-active">Proceeding</button>
        <button type="button" data-type="journal" class="">Journal Article</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap mcb-wrap mcb-wrap-hwqel1sdl one myfilter valign-top clearfix" style="">
        <div class="mcb-wrap-inner">

            <div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-ko9c4lj4p one column_list record  proceeding">
                <div class="list_item lists_2 clearfix">
                    <div class="animate fadeIn" data-anim-type="fadeIn">
                        <div class="list_right">My text 1</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-03xff3oxj one column_list record  proceeding">
                <div class="list_item lists_2 clearfix">
                    <div class="animate fadeIn" data-anim-type="fadeIn">
                        <div class="list_right">My text 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-kdy28db1t one column_list record  journal">
                <div class="list_item lists_2 clearfix">
                    <div class="animate" data-anim-type="fadeIn">
                        <div class="list_right">My text 3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```